# How to write a stored procedure to search data between 2 dates?

Tags: sql-server

This is the code I tried to replicate

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_REPORTING_Buku]
    @Kategori NVARCHAR(10),
    @Penerbit NVARCHAR(50),
    @Terbit DATE,
    @TerbitOld DATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        BookID, ISBN, Judul, Kategori, Terbit, Penerbit 
    FROM 
        dbo.tblM_Buku 
    WHERE 
        Kategori  '%' + @Kategori + '%'
        AND Penerbit  '%' + @Penerbit + '%'
        OR (Date BETWEEN @DateOld AND @Date)
END
```

but I tried to remove " Penerbit " and just use the kategori and date..

So I used

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_REPORTING_Buku]
    @Kategori NVARCHAR(10),
    @Date DATE,
    @DateOld DATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        BookID, ISBN, Judul, Kategori, Date
    FROM 
        dbo.tblM_Buku
    WHERE 
        Kategori  '%' + @Kategori + '%'
        OR (Date BETWEEN @DateOld AND @Date)
END
```

but I get an error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@DateOld"

How do I fix this?

Comment: But i already change it to date and dateold below the procedure

Comment: I already rename it to Date and DateOld , its no longer terbit and terbitold , and before on the tables i was using to practice there is only Terbit

Comment: I update my code hopely that useful

Comment: If that is really your code then it is not possible that you are getting that error as @DateOld is defined in your SP definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am agree with @Dale Burrel that you must not getting error as @DateOld is defined. However there is a problem in where clause of your procedure **'like'** keyword is missing and also use **parenthesis** after 'ALTER PROCEDURE' and before 'AS BEGIN'. Below is the corrected stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_REPORTING_Buku]
(
  @Kategori nvarchar(10),
  @Date date,
  @DateOld date
)
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT BookID, ISBN, Judul, Kategori, Date
  FROM dbo.tblM_Buku
  WHERE Kategori like '%' + @Kategori + '%'
  OR (Date BETWEEN @DateOld AND @Date)
END
```

Hope it will solve your problem.